# Why is my chrono duration not display the right value?

Tags: c++, frame-rate, c++-chrono

I am trying to create a FPS calculator for my game engine using the `chrono` library, but somehow after I convert the total run time of my engine, it becomes like pic related.

[image]

Notice the `-922337...` while it should be `1` and increment every line. 
Followings are how I declare the variables relevant to FPS calculation.

```
std::chrono::duration<double> printFPStime, runTime, deltaTime;
std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point frameStart, frameEnd;
int frames = 0;
float fps = 0.0f;
```

Followings are my source code for the FPS calculation.

```
void Game::CalculateFPS(){
    runTime += deltaTime;
    printFPStime += deltaTime;
    frames++;
    if (printFPStime >= std::chrono::seconds(1)){
        std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast
        <std::chrono::seconds>(runTime).count()
        << " sec, " << frames << 
        " fps" << std::endl;

        printFPStime -= std::chrono::seconds(1);
        frames = 0;
    }
}
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Try zero-initializing your durations, e.g. `printFPStime{}`.  If you don't initialize them, they have an indeterminate value.

Comment: OH MY GOD is this the real Howard Hinnant?!?!?!?!?! wtf?!?!?!

Comment: Hang on, I'll ask my wife....